# After upgrading from iTextSharp v5.5.6 tp v5.5.9 Adobe Reader reports error

Tags: pdf, itext

I've just upgraded from iTextSharp v5.5.6 to v5.5.9 and now one of my PDF documents report an error in Adobe Reader v11.0.17:
"An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem."

How can I see what the error is? Visually the document looks fine and I don't get the error when I open the PDF file in Google Chrome.

I tried looking at the changelog but can't see what has changed that is causing this error to appear.

Comment: No answer can be provided if you don't share the two PDFs.

Comment: It might be necessary, too, to share some code.

Comment: I can share the code and share the PDF but I would like to know how to get the error instead of just 'An error occurred'. I reverted back to v5.5.6 and the error disappears. When I know the error I can create a specific code snippit and a PDF without any privacy concerning data.